# How to randomly throw numbers in a 2D dimensional board

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 50x50 2D dimensional board with empty cells now. I want to fill 20% cells with 0, 30% cells with 1, 30% cells with 2 and 20% cells with 3. How to randomly throw these 4 numbers onto the board with the percentages?

```
  import numpy as np
  from numpy import random

  dim = 50
  map = [[" "for i in range(dim)] for j in range(dim)]
  print(map)
```

Comment: Read up `np.random.choice`

Comment: Do you want these exact percentages, in random positions, or do you want numbers drawn randomly at these proportions? (Big difference, since you will not get _exactly_ the proportion in the second case.)

Comment: @alexis exact percentages in random positions

Comment: Good, then a shuffle-type approach is the way to go. You've got answers for both interpretations already...

Answer (score 2):

One way to get this kind of randomness would be to start with a random permutation of the numbers from 0 to the total number of cells you have minus one.

```
perm = np.random.permutation(2500)
```

now you split the permutation according the proportions you want to get and treat the entries of the permutation as the indices of the array.

```
array = np.empty(2500)
p1 = int(0.2*2500)
p2 = int(0.3*2500)
p3 = int(0.3*2500)
array[perm[range(0, p1)]] = 0
array[perm[range(p1, p1 + p2)]] = 1
array[perm[range(p1 + p2, p3)]] = 2
array[perm[range(p1 + p2 + p3, 2500)]] = 3
array = array.reshape(50, 50)
```

This way you ensure the proportions for each number.

Comment: Nice! Clear and to the point, and it uses numpy's mass assignment to do everything without loops.

Answer (score 2):

Since the percentages sum up to 1, you can start with a board of zeros

```
bsize = 50
board = np.zeros((bsize, bsize))
```

In this approach the board positions are interpreted as 1D postions, then we need a set of position equivalent to 80% of all positions.

```
for i, pos in enumerate(np.random.choice(bsize**2, int(0.8*bsize**2), replace=False)):
    # the fisrt 30% will be set with 1
    if i < int(0.3*bsize**2):
        board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 1
    # the second 30% (between 30% and 60%) will be set with 2
    elif i < int(0.6*bsize**2):
        board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 2
    # the rest 20% (between 60% and 80%) will be set with 3
    else:
        board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 3
```

At the end the last 20% of positions will remain as zeros

---

As suggested by @alexis in commentaries, this approach could became more simple by using `shuffle` method from `random` module:

from random import shuffle

```
bsize = 50
board = np.zeros((bsize, bsize))

l = list(range(bsize**2))
shuffle(l)

for i, pos in enumerate(l):
        # the fisrt 30% will be set with 1
        if i < int(0.3*bsize**2):
            board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 1
        # the second 30% (between 30% and 60%) will be set with 2
        elif i < int(0.6*bsize**2):
            board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 2
        # the rest 20% (between 60% and 80%) will be set with 3
        elif i < int(0.8*bsize**2):
            board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 3
```

The last 20% of positions will remain as zeros again.

Comment: May want to consider using NumPy's own [`ndenumerate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) for this approach

Comment: @BradSolomon I've clicked in the link and I do not noted any difference in comparison to python's built-in `enumerate`. Is there any advantage using `ndenumerate` instead of `enumerate` ?

Comment: `ndenumerate()` will iterate across all dimensions of an `np` array. `enumerate` only enumerates along the top dimension. Since you are using it on a 1-dimensional number range, there is no reason to prefer one to the other.

Comment: You are using `np.random.choice()` to select out the 20% that should be set to zero, then you use proportions for the other three values. Why make it so complicated? Just randomize (shuffle) the entire `range(50*50)`, and apply your proportions.

Comment: @alexis Shuffle passed by my mind but I was thinking a way to apply it directly to the board, but nothing came to my mind. I will add this approach to the answer, it really seems to be more simple.

Comment: To make it even simpler, use slicing: `for pos in l[0:int(0.3*bsize**2)]: board[pos//bsize][pos%bsize] = 1`; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `np.random.choice` to shuffle indices, then filling those indices with repeats of the inserted ints.  It will fill the array in the exact proportions that you specify:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(444)

board = np.zeros(50 * 50, dtype=np.uint8).flatten()

# The "20% cells with 0" can be ignored since that is the default.
#
# This will work as long as the proportions are "clean" ints
# (I.e. mod to 0; 2500 * 0.2 is a clean 500.  Otherwise, need to do some rounding.)

rpt = (board.shape[0] * np.array([0.3, 0.3, 0.2])).astype(int)
repl = np.repeat([1, 2, 3], rpt)

idx = np.random.choice(board.shape[0], size=repl.size, replace=False)

board[idx] = repl
board = board.reshape((50, 50))
```

Resulting frequencies:

```
>>> np.unique(board, return_counts=True)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8), array([500, 750, 750, 500]))
>>> board
array([[1, 3, 2, ..., 3, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, ..., 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, ..., 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

#### Approach

Flatten the board.  Easier to work with indices when the board is (temporarily) one-dimensional.

`rpt` is a 1d vector of the number of repeats per int.  It gets "zipped" together with `[1, 2, 3]` to create `repl`, which is length 2000.  (80% of the size of the board; you don't need to worry about the 0s in this example.)

The indices of the flattened array are effectively shuffled (`idx`), and the length of this shuffled array is constrained to the size of the replacement candidates.  Lastly, those indices in the 1d board are filled with the replacements, after which it can be made 2d again.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach (admittedly it's probabilistic so you won't get perfect proportions as the solution proposed by Brad Solomon)

```
import numpy as np
res = np.random.random((50, 50))

zeros = np.where(res <= 0.2, 0, 0)
ones = np.where(np.logical_and(res <= 0.5, res > 0.2), 1, 0)
twos = np.where(np.logical_and(res <= 0.8, res > 0.5), 2, 0)
threes = np.where(res > 0.8, 3, 0)

final_result = zeros + ones + twos + threes
```

Running

```
np.unique(final_result, return_counts=True)
```

yielded

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([499, 756, 754, 491]))
```